# How can you change color of a particular variable displayed in the same line?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to change the color of val without changing the color of "Solution" and have them display in the same line (code shown below)?

```
result.innerText = "Solution:" + val.toFixed(2);
```

I know that you can add

```
result.style="color:red";
```

but that changes the color of the entire line including "solution:" when I run;

```
<div id="result" align ="center"></div>
```

EDIT: Changes I made by adding pseudo element and classes but nothing is displayed apart from "Solution"

```
        val = sumsc/sumcr;
        var result = document.querySelector('#result');
        if(isNaN(sumsc/sumcr)){
            val=0.00;
            result.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
            result.className = "white";


        else if(val<3 & val>0.1){

            result.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
            result.className = "red";
        }
        else if(val>3 & val<3.5){

            result.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
            result.className = "pink";
        }
        else if(val>3.5){

            result.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
            result.className = "green";
        }
```

```
        #result{
          text-align:center;
        }

        #result::before {
          content: "Solution: ";
          color: black;
        }

        .white {
          color: white;
        }
        .red {
          color: red;
        }
        .pink{
          color: pink;
        }
        .green{
          color: green;
        }
```

Comment: You could use two seperate elements, one with the word "Solution" and one with your value in.

Comment: @alea, that does not display everything in one line

Comment: @n350 using the `span` element will keep it inline

Comment: @EdwardNewsome, I tried that and it did not work (see comments below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate might be to put the span in the markup, `<div id="result">Solution:<span class="solutionval"></span></div>` then just change the text/value there.

```
let resutltTextSpan = document.getElementById('result')
  .getElementsByClassName('solutionval')[0];
resutltTextSpan.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
```

Here I use a function so you can see simple changes over time with set of timeout functions that call it with a value.

More information on adding, removing, toggle etc. of classes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

EDIT: added toggle of class as that might be most elegant given the comments.

```js
function setVal(val = 0) {
  let resutltTextSpan = document.getElementById('result')
  .getElementsByClassName('solutionval')[0];
  resutltTextSpan.innerText = val.toFixed(2);

  // now we can do other things 
  if (val === 0) {
    resutltTextSpan.classList.add("unset");
  }
  if (val > 0 && val < 9000) {
    resutltTextSpan.classList.add("good");
  }
  resutltTextSpan.classList.toggle("bad",(val > 9000 && val <= 9300) );
  if (val > 9900) {
    resutltTextSpan.classList.add("ugly");
  }
}

let val = 456;

setVal(); //use default 0 since we pass nothing
setTimeout(function() {
  val = 9200.2455;
  setVal(val);
}, 5000);
// change it after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
  val = 9934.56;
  setVal(val);
}, 10000);
```

```css
#retult {
  text-align: center;
}

.solutionval.unset {
  color: #0000ff;
}

.solutionval {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.solutionval.good {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.solutionval.bad {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.solutionval.ugly {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">Solution:<span class="solutionval"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding `val` with a span and adding styles to it should work:

```html
result.innerHTML = 'Solution: <span class="red">' + val.toFixed(2) + '</span>';
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: It won't work as you change `innerText`, not `innerHTML`

Comment: Just as a side comment, this is one of the rare examples of `innerHTML` being used sensibly on Stack Overflow. Most of the time `innerHTML` is used as if it's the only way to programmatically change the content of a tag, in cases where `innerText` would make much more sense because there's no markup, and even the possibility of text being incorrectly interpreted as markup.

Comment: I would use a `class="something"` rather than `style="color:red"`

Comment: @matrixersp, that changes the color but the word "solution" does not display

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a ::before pseudo element of the word "solution" - this allows you to set the value of the number and have the text automatically placed as the first child of the div.

EDIT: I have addded a ternary equation to allow the changing of the color based on the value. Note that this has to be determined from the number not the .toFixed(2) value since that is now a string. This can be used as regular if / else statements if there are more than two options.

Also - it is better to apply styles via adding / removing classes than directly targetting the style attribute withing the JS.

```js
var val = 13.789;
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
result.innerText = val.toFixed(2);
val > 10
  ? result.className = "red"
  : result.className = "blue"
```

```css
#result{
  text-align:center;
}

#result::before {
  content: "Solution ";
  color: black;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"><div>
```

Comment: that works, but how would you change the colors of `val` based on if statements (different colors for different range of numbers)?

Comment: I have added logic to the js to apply one of two classes based on the value - read the edit text in my answer to see what has happened.

Comment: I tried applying your method using if-else statements (see code in main post) but not only am I not able to change any color but val is not being displayed at all. What I am doing wrong? ps- thanks for the help!